# How to apply i18n to Rails Ransack's sort_link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm using Ranksack to make search and form sorting functionality. Among them, I found that I can use sort_link to sort the table by "Name":

```
<th scope="col"><%= sort_link(@query, :name) %></th>
```

However, I need to apply ``:name``` to i18n display. But if I apply it, the sorting function of sort_link is invalid:

```
<th scope="col"><%= sort_link(@query, t('task_name')) %></th>
```

How can I modify it to have both sorting and i18n functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass label as a block - [refer](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/e59b4ae7999f295f1042b7637d83023aa61809bf/docs/docs/getting-started/simple-mode.md#search-link-helper)

```
<th scope="col">
  <%= sort_link(@query, :name) do %>
    <%= t('task_name') %>
  <% end %>
</th>
```